# Using RestTemplate with local json file

Tags: java, json, spring, resttemplate, stubbing

#### Background

I'm writing a web service that makes calls to an external api. This api has not yet been put into production. As such, when I make a call to my web service in my dev environment, I want to stub out the responses that it returns. Note: this is not a unit testing question.

#### My Solution So Far

The api calls are made using RestTemplate from the lovely Spring people, the url of which is held in application.properties. This has allowed me to set different urls for different environments using Active Profiles. So, for example, application-dev.properties holds a different url.
The dev url is ideally a pointer to a json file under resources/.

#### My Issue

I can't seem to get RestTemplate to pick up the local json file. The url I'm using is:

```
url = "file://staticJson.json"
```

However that comes up with a

```
Object of class [sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection] must be an instance of class java.net.HttpURLConnection
```

And now I'm unsure of how to proceed, or if this is even possible without extending RestTemplate.

Any directions to try or solutions would be fantastic.

If any more information is required I'll do my best to provide it asap.

Comment: By looking the stacktrace you should be aware of you cannot use a file instead of an http resource in this way (file:// is clearly different from http://).

Comment: So the not possible with RestTemplate option. Damn, was hoping that wouldn't be the case.